# MongoDb query aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

```
db.grades.aggregate({'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'score':{'$gte':65}}}, {'$sort':{'score':1}}, {'$limit':1})
```

I can't work out why this isn't working. It should "Find all exam scores greater than or equal to 65, and sort those scores from lowest to highest."

It gives an error of:

> Error: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$gte'", "code" : 15952 } : aggregate failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think db.grades.find, sort, limit is extremely simple.  I like it.  If the need it to use an aggregation pipeline to do more advanced work, then just think of aggregation as a set of steps.  It's not like SQL (where you cram everything into a single statement).

Instead, use the aggregation pipeline to build up your query in layers.  Execute the following **by adding one element at a time** and you'll see what I mean.

```
db.grades.aggregate(
  {'$match':{'score':{'$gte':65}}},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'scoreMax':{'$max':'$score'}}},
  {'$sort':{'scoreMax':-1}},
  {'$limit':1}
)
```

**$match** pulls scores >= 65.  Execute your pipeline with just that element and you'll see all matching scores.

```
db.grades.aggregate(
  {'$match':{'score':{'$gte':65}}}
)
```

**$group** gets a max score per student_id (that, I assume, is what your professor wants you to work with)

```
db.grades.aggregate(
  {'$match':{'score':{'$gte':65}}},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'scoreMax':{'$max':'$score'}}}
)
```

**$sort** puts that aggregated student list in order (smartest to dumbest)

```
db.grades.aggregate(
  {'$match':{'score':{'$gte':65}}},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'scoreMax':{'$max':'$score'}}},
  {'$sort':{'scoreMax':-1}}
)
```

**$limit** pulls just the top student and her score.

```
db.grades.aggregate(
  {'$match':{'score':{'$gte':65}}},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'scoreMax':{'$max':'$score'}}},
  {'$sort':{'scoreMax':-1}},
  {'$limit':1}
)
```

Comment: Well explained! Thank you everyone though! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$gte` insde group. You can use a `$match` agregation pipeline stage before `$group` stage and filter by `$gte` there.
Anyway, I don't think you need an aggregation for your query; 
Does this solve your problem:

```
db.grades.find({'score':{'$gte':65}}).sort({'score':1}).limit(1)
```

?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your way works but I needed it to use aggregation. :)